# How to match multiple strings, where one is a 'does not contain'?

Tags: regex

Assume I have a list of strings in memory (basically String1 - String100)

```
String1
String2
...
String11
String12
...
String20
String21
...
```

What is one way, using Regular Expressions, that can do the following?

'Match all strings that do not contain "String1" but do contain "String10" Or "String3"'

Comment: It seems that none of the strings in your list should match since no string contains both `string10` and `string3`...

Comment: I'd like it to match if the string does not contain String1, but does contain String10 or String3. Sorry, i'll edit the original with "Or".

Comment: So, is this actually language specific; if so, C# or python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
^(?=.*String(?:10|3)\b)(?!.*String1\b)
```

This will match if the string contains either `String10` or `String3`, but only if it doesn't contain `String1` (assuming that these words are delimited somehow, e. g. by whitespace or other non-alphanumeric characters).

The match itself will be zero-length, so you just need to check if there is a match:

```
>>> strings = ["String10 String1 String5", "String4", "String10 String2",
...            "String1 String3", "String4 String3"]
>>> regex = re.compile(r"^(?=.*String(?:10|3)\b)(?!.*String1\b)")
>>> [string for string in strings if regex.search(string)]
['String10 String2', 'String4 String3']
```

**Explanation:**

```
regex = re.compile(r"""
        ^         # Match the start of the string
       (?=        # Assert that the following can be matched here:
        .*        # Any string, followed by
        String    # the word "String" and
        (?:10|3)  # either the number 10 or 3.
        \b        # Make sure the word ends here (don't match "String100"!)
       )          # End of lookahead. We're still at the start of the string!
       (?!        # Assert that the following can't be matched here
        .*        # Any string, followed by
        String1   # "String1"
        \b        # Make sure the word ends here (don't match "String10"!)
       )          # End of lookahead
       """, re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I need. I'm testing it now. If you wouldn't mind, could you break it down piece by piece (more-so than you already did)? I really want to understand this, but the lookahead documentation isn't exactly clear to me yet.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex for that.
In Python you can use something like this:

```
>>> string1 = 'bla'
>>> string2 = 'ble'
>>> string3 = 'blue'
>>> 
>>> the_string = 'blabla'
>>> string1 in the_string and string2 not in the_string and string3 not in the_string
True
```

Comment: I must use Regex, it is a project requirement as my example above is very simple, and the actual implementation is a lot more complex.